# How to break line inside a paste0() function in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I'm trying to print 2 lines of text in shinydashboard server section, and "\n" doesn't seem to work

```
    output$textbox_ID <- renderText(
    {
           paste0("Apples \n Bananas")
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `\n` is unicode line break, for shiny you need HTML line break i.e. `<br>`.
Here is a solution using `renderUI` since I am not sure if it is possible to insert HTML tags in `renderText`.

## UI

```
uiOutput('textbox_ID')
```

## Server

```
output$textbox_ID <- renderUI(
{
  HTML(paste0("Apples",br()," Bananas"))
}
```

)

If you do not need to retrieve something from the server side, then you can use the following in the *UI* directly:

```
helpText( HTML(paste0("Apples",br()," Bananas")))
#OR
HTML("Apples <br> Bananas")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and no HTML involved:

```
 paste0("Apples ","\n", "Bananas") #
```